# How to get Android Studio to open a clicked file in the currently active text editor

Tags: android-studio

In other text editors/IDEs (all that I have ever used), when you have a split window showing two or more editors within the same window and you click or somehow navigate to a different file than the one you are currently viewing it will show up in the currently active editor. Android Studio does not do this. When you navigate to a different file it will open that file in whatever editor it exists in, either your current one or a different one. I do not want this functionality and I want to somehow change it to how other IDEs work, i.e., open the file I select in the currently active editor regardless of it already exists somewhere else.

This will produce the same file existing in multiple text editors, but also this is useful so you can have one part of a file open on the right and be working on a different part of the same file on the left, for example, but also just works better with my work flow to no matter what put the file I select in the right editor if that's where I want it. Otherwise I have to drag and drop every time it routes me to the wrong editor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got it right but if you split the editor tabs (menu `Window` -> `Editor Tabs` -> `Split Right` for instance) and then you click on any file of the project then the file will be opened in the panel currently selected.

Tested with Android Studio Iguana.